# Использование Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps

Tags: xamarin.forms

Я использую Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps 3.3.0. Карта загружается лишь частично, т.е. при прокрутке влево/вправо не обновляется, а показывается лишь сетка. В чем может быть причина

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос снят. Слетал ключ в google console и не отрабатывали строки

```
 <uses-permission android:name="mypackage.android.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />               <permission android:name="mypackage.android.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

в AndroidManifest, но при этом частично карта загружалась.

Помогло просто новое указание имени сборки и отпечатка SHA-1